# jQuery: select style attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select  with a specific style attribute?

```
<div style="width: 420px; text-align: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;">
```

I'm trying:

```
$("div[style='width: 420px; text-align: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;']);
```

but nothing gets selected.

Comment: Why don't you use classes/ids for selecting stuff? And why do you use inline `style=` styles?

Comment: @thejh There are good reasons for using inline styles at times.  When you have many objects that differ from a base style in unique ways each time, setting up a new ID every time is often unnecessary or for dynamic code, not applicable.

Comment: I'm trying to extract data from an existing html page.

Comment: Try looking for an ancestor/ descendent with an ID, then use `.children('div')` or `.parent()` etc to get the DIV in question.

Comment: You do know this works without the typo, see my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a style selector in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625107/is-there-a-style-selector-in-jquery)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your example works for me, in Chrome at least, once I corrected the typo of the missing " at the end of the line.

```
$("div[style='width: 420px; text-align: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;']");
```

[See this demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/TuBbm/)

Comment: This is a highly specific solution. What if you're looking for one style attribute, e.g. `text-align: left`?

Answer (score 10):

To my knowledge, there's no way to do that using a jQuery selector, but you can use the [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method instead:

```
$("div").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return $this.css("width") == "420px"
        && $this.css("text-align") == "left"
        && $this.css("margin-top") == "10px"
        && $this.css("margin-bottom") == "10px";
});
```

Comment: Cache $(this). Please. For the sake of my CPU.

Comment: OK, no one in the right mind would actually do what the questioner tried - however, filter is a great trick for a lot of good things!

Answer (score 3):

(This does not answer the question. However, if the person who wrote the HTML page had used classes instead of the style attribute, then the OP would not have this problem.)

```
.foo { width: 420px; text-align: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; }

<div class="foo"> </div>

$("div.foo")
```

Answer (score 2):

maybe try

```
$('div').filter(function() {
    var self = $(this);
    return self.width() === 420 &&
           self.css('margin-top') === '10px' &&
           self.css('margin-bottom') === '10px' &&
           self.css('text-align') === 'left';
});
```

It would be easier however to select the element by one attribute such as id or css class, or by it's position to an element that has an id or css class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1>Hello header</h1>
<p style="color: red;">Hello My</p>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p[style='color: red;']").fadeOut("10000",function(){
    $("h1").hide();
});
});
</script>
```

The style should be exact same as of in the

tag and $ selector