# Targeting a DOM element with JQuery inline style property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to target a div with a specific style using `jQuery`. I initially read over a similar question here: [jQuery: select style attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291605/jquery-select-style-attribute).

I am unable to target with an `id` selector as I don't have access to the markup that makes up the page I am styling, only the header and the footer. I know it's messy but it's the only solution I've got.

Anyways, I had been doing things like this to override the different `css` properties of each of the elements:

```
 $('Dom element').css({
           "CSS property": "CSS Value"
 });
```

and it was working perfectly. However the issue I am having is I'm trying to target an element that has no `id`, `name`, `alt` or `class` it is just a div with some inline `css`.

I attempted to do this:

```
 $("div[style='margin:0 auto;width:74px;']").css("width", "100%");
```

But that did not work. I then did this:

```
console.log($("div[style='margin:0 auto;width:74px;']"));
```

and I can see the div being output in the developers console. I'm wondering If I'm missing something? Again, I know it's probably not best practice the way I'm going about this, but I've no alternatives.

This is the `html` of the particular `div` I am trying to access and modify:

```
<div style="margin:0 auto;width:74px">
      <div style="float: none;">
```

I should point out that I managed to target the `div` in the code sample above and modify the inline css through `jQuery` doing the following:

```
$("div[style='float:right;']").css({
              "float":"none"
});
```

So it's making me wonder If I am missing something blatantly obvious.

Anyways, thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is selecting them based on the property value as a string not some interpretation of the values thus with the `=` selector they **must match exactly including whitespace and what not** - your selector has an ending `;` and your element does not. Assuming those are not typos.

Comment: How do you know width isn't being applied? It might not appear in the console... Try adding a background color

Comment: @prodigitalson, that fixed it, thank you, been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is selecting them based on the property value as a string not some interpretation of the values thus with the `=` selector they **must match exactly including whitespace and what not** - your selector has an ending `;` and your element does not. Assuming those are not typos.

Comment: They weren't typos, thanks again, will accept this answer when SO allows me. Cheers

Comment: Sounds good... just adding it as an answer for others and points ;-)