# Selecting a div without a .Class or #Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, it is much easier for me if it is possible to select all the divs that match a particular set of similar style attributes.

**Example of div that I want to select**

```
<div style="background-image: url(http://localhost/website/images/template/markers/cluster.png); height: 34px; line-height: 34px; width: 34px; text-align: center; cursor: pointer; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: absolute; font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold; top: 78.15521871251985px; left: 725.3256078213453px; background-position: 0px 0px; ">15</div>
```

Other than this div, other divs that needs to be selected can be similar to this one, but with say different `height` and `top` `left` positions. However, the good thing is that the `background-image url()` remains the same.

How can this selection be made with jQuery? Thank you !!

### EDIT

**Surrounding Code**
*Easier to provide a screencap*

[image]

Comment: left: 725.3256078213453px; ????

Comment: I dunno what's worse, having inline styles like this in the first place or querying dom elements based on those inline styles

Comment: i think you missed the whole point of jquery. just add a class period

Comment: The inline styles were created by a google map library and I dont want to dig into the library and edit the codes

Comment: While I agree inline styles are bad and selecting from them is even worse, many libraries and CSS grid systems generate them and it is common to see obscure values like the ones above because they are percentage-based.

Comment: Please show us more surrounding code. Given that these are markers, they could be selected with child combinator (`parent > child`) with some reference element as their parent. Also, it's quite probable that Google Maps API provides a method to conveniently retrieve all markers at once.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the code in the original post. Everything within `#map_canvas` is generated either by Google Maps API V3 or the Gmap library that I'm using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**I don't think it's a good idea**, but you can select elements by specific **inline** style with this:

```
$('div[style*="height: 34px"]')
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/etuyom/edit#javascript,html,live)

Comment: A note on this: This works only with inline styles as in your example.

Comment: This will give false matches when the style cssText contains `"height: 34px;"`, for example `"line-height: 34px"`

Comment: `$('div[style*=" height: 34px"]')` works because background-image is always the first style.

Comment: I would prefer to select using the background-image, because the desired divs to select all have the same background-image

Comment: Yeah works, too `$('div[style*="background-image: url(http://localhost/website/images/template/markers/cluster.png);"]')` __BUT yuk!__

Comment: as far as i know, you should be careful of the "phrases" on this one. a slight missing/added space can mean getting selected or not. `"height: 34px"` is not the same as `"height:34px"`

Comment: @Joseph because the code is generated by google maps, the format should always be the same.

Comment: well, just saying. just incase :D

Comment: For the generic case, you need to use [filters in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625107/is-there-a-style-selector-in-jquery).

Comment: Dirty, dirty, dirty...!! I can not understand why people still deny to use classes or ids. EVERYBODY'S life would be so much SIMPLER.