# javascript select by CSS and toggle display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a javascript newbie so go easy on me.  I'm wanting to select a bunch of text that is identifiable only by inline CSS (not classes or ids or anything), and create a toggle that turns it on and off. So -- find everything with backgroundColor = '#eed6b4'  and toggle display='none' / 'inline-block'

Needing the javascript and html... thx

=====================

This is what I tried originally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function toggleVisibility() {

       var codeNum = document.getElementsByClassName('syntaxHighlightingPlugin');
             i = codeNum.length;

       while(i--) {
            codeNum[1].style.backgroundColor = '#eed6b4';

          if(codeNum.style.display == 'inline-block')
             codeNum.style.display = 'none';
          else
             codeNum.style.display = 'inline-block';
       }
    }

</script>


<button type="button" onclick="toggleVisibility();"> Hide numbers (for copying) </button>
```

Oh, and as I replied to a comment, the twist on this is that it's for text rendered by a TWiki plugin, so I have no control over the resulting CSS --- which, as I said, has **no classes**  --- also, since it's rendered, I think I may need to use something like `getComputedStyle` (?).

Comment: People are downvoting you because although you are a newbie you should display that you have at least put forth some sort of effort.|

Also, inline CSS is generally bad practice. Put a class on all that stuff and you can grab that class easily via javascript.

Comment: Is this something you wrote? Or are you working on code written by someone else? Either way you should put a class or id to do this for all those elements.

Comment: Not a class I wrote -- it's for line numbers in code rendered by the syntax highlighting plugin in TWiki -- wanting to be able to hide the numbers so users can select and copy just the code. The plugin renders the numbers with just inline CSS, best distinguishable as far as I can tell by that particular bg color. I'm thinking now that the issue is even more complicated --- since it's rendered, may need something involving getComputedStyle.  Really I'm wanting to get all text _rendered_ with that bg color, and have a button that toggles hiding it,

Answer (score 2):

It's generally bad practice to use inline css, and to make your Javascript dependant on that inline CSS is also not a good idea. However, if you wanted to select an element based on the value of an attribute, you can use the attribute value selector like this:

```
$("[style='backgroundColor *= #eed6b4']").hide();
```

Reminder: This uses jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class to that background color and then filter by class name $(".classname").

OR

You could add a new selector like explained here:
[Is there a style selector in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625107/is-there-a-style-selector-in-jquery)

Not necessarily a great idea, but you could add a new Sizzle selector for it:

> `$.expr[':'].width = function(elem, pos, match) {
>      return $(elem).width() == parseInt(match[3]);
>   }`
>   which you could then use like so:
>
> `$('div:width(970)')`
>   //That's going to be horrifically slow, though, so you'd want to narrow down on the number >of elements you're comparing with something like :
>
> `$('#navbar>div:width(970)')`
>   //to only select those divs that are direct descendants of the navbar, which also have a >width of 970px.